# cin stream error

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    if (cin >> i)
    {
        //ok
    }
    else
    {
        //error
        cin.setstate(std::ios_base::goodbit);
    }
}
```

Why can't I set `goodbit` through setstate() to clear out the `failbit` instead of cin.clear()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `setstate` combines the current state with whatever state you're passing it with a bitwise `OR`, ergo the fail bit doesn't get cleared (set to zero).

So assume:

```
Assume a very simple state mechanism:
00
^^
||
|\
| the fail bit
 \
   the ok bit
```

Doing `setstate(okbit)` when your state is `01` is just going to give you `11` (look ma, the fail bit is still set) so really all you're doing is screwing up the internal stream state. You should really avoid using `setstate` altogether.

[Click](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/setstate/) for reference.

Comment: For the record: `goodbit` is actually zero, and the initial value for the state bits. The descripton of how `setstate` works is otherwise very good.